# Localization of $k[t]$ at a prime ideal is not a finitely generated $k[t]$-algebra?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, localization

Let $k$ be a field (infinite and algebraicaly closed), consider the prime ideal $(t)$ in $k[t]$.

Consider the localization of $k[t]$ at $(t)$: $k[t]_{(t)}$.

Now $k[t]_{(t)}$ is a $k[t]$-algebra. I want to show that $k[t]_{(t)}$ is not a finitely  generated $k[t]$-algebra. How do I show that? Any help will appreciated.

Comment: You've inverted infinitely many things which are algebraically independent over $k[t]$. Think about why $\mathbb{Q}$ is not finitely generated as a $\mathbb{Z}$-algebra, and from there consider why $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$ (localization at $p$) as a $\mathbb{Z}$ algebra is not finitely generated. The case with $k[t]$ is basically the same idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any field as a $k$-algebra $$k(t) = k[t,\{\frac{1}{f(t)}, f \in k[t] \text{ monic irreducible}\}]$$

As a $k$-vector space the basis are the $t^k, k \ge 0$ and the $\frac{t^n}{f(t)^m},m \ge 1,  n < \deg(f), f \in k[t]$ monic irreducible.